# GitHubなどのホスティングサービスを利用しないRequest-Pull機能の利用は可能か

Tags: git

Request-Pullの仕組みは開発クローンで変更した内容をベアリポジトリにPushしたとき、Pushによりベアリポジトリが更新されたことを他の開発者にメールで知らせることと理解しています。
ネットなどの情報からは、その機能を働かせるためにホスティングサービス側が提供しているGitHubなどを利用しなければならないとあります。
本当のところ、GitHubなどのホスティングサービスを使用せず、Request-Pull機能の利用はできないのでしょうか。
もし、GitHubなどのホスティングサービスを使用しないでRequest-Pull機能の利用が可能なら、その方法を御教授ください。

目的：クローンからPushしてベアリポジトリが更新されたことを他の開発者にメールで通知しPullを促す
条件：GitHubを使わず、Git（SourceTree，Git for Windows）のみで実現する
環境：クローンノンベアリポジトリ配置PC - Windows10 Pro
クローンノンベアリポジトリでのCommit/Push/Pullソフトウェア - SourceTree
ベアリポジトリ配置PC - Windows10 Pro for Workstation
ネットワーク：イントラネット

上記環境に於いて、目的は達成できない、は正しいですか？
GitHubのようなホスティングサービスでのみ目的は達成できる、は正しいですか？
上記環境でできるならば、その具体的な方法を教えてください。
以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `Git`という単語やタグを使ってしまうから質問者も回答者もそれに囚われてズレてしまうのでは？ この記事 [バージョン管理システム - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0) の `リポジトリ - 分散型バージョン管理` ように特定のソフトウェア/システムに注目しないような形に方向を変えた方が良さそうです。

Comment: そうは言ってもGit関連でこんな記事があるのでもしかしたら参考になるかもしれません。[How to synchronize two git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4860166/9014308), [7.12 Git のさまざまなツール - バンドルファイルの作成](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%96%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90), [Git bundle ファイルを受け取って既存のリポジトリにマージし Pull Request を作る手順](https://blog.kyanny.me/entry/2016/08/17/131018)

Comment: 「ホスティングサービスを利用しない (利用したくない？)」理由も書いておいた方が、より具体的な回答につながるかもしれません。 / 例えば GitLab などを使えば外部のホスティングサービスではなく **自分の管理するサーバ上** で運用することも可能です。

Comment: この辺の記事で何か出来そうな感じです。参考にしてみてください。Workstation版[Windows10パソコン上にGitサーバを立ててみた - LinuxサーバがないけどGitサーバを運用したい場合の対処法](https://imamachi-n.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/09/170331), Server版[WindowsにGitサーバを構築してSSHでアクセスする](https://www.tdi.co.jp/miso/windows-server-git-ssh)

Answer (score 1):

[`git request-pull`コマンド](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull)の実例は [5.2 Git での分散作業 - プロジェクトへの貢献 > フォークされた公開プロジェクト](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%88%86%E6%95%A3%E4%BD%9C%E6%A5%AD-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%B2%A2%E7%8C%AE#r_public_project)にあります。

この例において、なぜホスティングサービスが必要かというと、自分が行った作業内容(を含むリポジトリ)を、メンテナが参照可能な場所に公開しないといけないからです。

メンテナンス対象リポジトリに自分が`git push`可能であるならば、自分の作業を直接そこへ`push`する運用も採用できます(同ページ [非公開な小規模のチーム](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%88%86%E6%95%A3%E4%BD%9C%E6%A5%AD-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%B2%A2%E7%8C%AE#r_private_team) のような環境)。この場合は別にホスティングサービスは不要です。

---

コメントを読んで思ったのですが、質問したいのは `request-pull` ではなく[`post-receive`](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA-Git-%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF#_%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)についてなのかな、と思いました。

こちらは、[githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)というGitの機能で、`request-pull`とは直接関係はありません。

[`post-receive-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email)は、このhook機能を利用して、誰かが`git push`したらその情報をメールで送信する、というスクリプトです。

> hooksディレクトリにpost-receive.sampleとpost-receive-mail.sampleが存在しません。

これは自分自身で作成して、自分自身で設置する必要が有ります([8.3 Git のカスタマイズ - Git フック](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA-Git-%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)に設置方法など説明があります)。
…が、一般的で有用なものは[`contrib/hooks`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/hooks)として提供されており、これを少しカスタマイズすれば利用できるようになっています。
そのうちのひとつが`post-receive-email`です。

ただし、それらは大抵Unix系OSを前提としており、Windowsは考慮されていないと思います(ので、やはり基本的には自分で実装する必要があるでしょう)。
例えば、`post-receive-email`では[`/usr/sbin/sendmail`がセットアップされている前提](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15beaaa/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email#L704-L711)で書かれています。

---

なぜ `post-receive.sample` や `post-receive-mail.sample` が存在していると考えているのでしょう？(なにかドキュメントを読んでそう考えられていると思うのですが、それは何でしょう？)
`post-receive.sample` は [2011年ごろ(v1.7.7)に削除されているよう](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d714b11df2b65e5f4272c1616e561930010be90)なので、何か資料を参考にされているのであれば、記述が古すぎる可能性があります。

Comment: 回答から察するとRequest-Pull機能は、環境・管理者と利用者間でアクセス権限を区別することにより生まれた機能と理解しました。　なるほど、いくら探してもpost-receive.sample/post-receive-mail.sampleが作成されず、情報も見つからないはずですね。　具体的な優しい説明に感謝します。　またリンクの情報についてもありがとうございました。

Comment: 本文に追記しましたが、あまり聞きたいことに対して回答ができている気がしません。どういう環境で何を実現したいのかを具体的に書いていただければ、期待する回答が付きやすくなるかなと感じます。

Comment: @Yuetsuro 質問に関わる内容はコメント欄ではなく質問を直接 [編集] して追記してください。コメント欄はあくまで簡易なやり取りをするための機能なので、改行を含めることはできません。

Comment: 目的：クローンからPushしてベアリポジトリが更新されたことを開発者にメールで通知させ、Pullを促す
条件：GitHubを使わずGitのみで実現
環境：クローンノンベアリポジトリ配置PC - Windows10 Pro、
      クローンノンベアリポジトリでのCommit/Push/Pullソフトウェア - SourceTree、
      ベアリポジトリ配置PC - Windows10 Pro for Workstation
ネットワーク：イントラネット
本文への追記から、Request-PullではなくGitフック機能を利用するのが正しいように思えてきました。 当初、目的を実現させるためにベアリポジトリのhooksディレクトリでpost-receive.sampleとpost-receive-mail.sampleを設定すれば実現できると考えていましたが、 hooksディレクトリにpost-receive.sampleとpost-receive-mail.sampleが存在しません。 目的の実現は、Git fooks機能を利用するべき、なのでしょうか。 Git fooks機能が正しいなら、なぜ２つの*.sampleは存在していないのでしょうか。 Git hooks機能の仕組みを理解できていないため、新規にファイルを起こすにも機能の流れが理解できずにいます。

Answer (score 0):

GitHubですとアカウントが用意され、アクセス制御が行われていますが、git単体にはそのような制御はありません。そのため、送信者がPull Requestを送り込む時点で、送信者には送り先のリポジトリへの書き込み権が存在することになり、mergeまで実行できてしまいます。

アクセス制御を行わず完全に切り離された環境で実現するシンプルな方法として[git diff / git apply](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%88%86%E6%95%A3%E4%BD%9C%E6%A5%AD-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E9%81%8B%E5%96%B6#r_patches_from_email)が用意されています。git diffではメール原稿が出力されるのでそれをメールとして送信します。受信者はパッチに問題がなければgit applyで取り込むことができます。

Comment: まずは「git単体にはそのような制御はありません。」の前置きをありがとうございます。　私は開発者がGit Pushした時のコメント内容をメールで送信するしか手がないと考えていました。　パッチ内容が分かるのはLinux的に作業ができるので良い方法だと思いました。　DewaさんとSayuriさんの回答を見直しまして、検討させて戴きます。　ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

質問は、オンプレで動く(いわゆる)GitHubクローンを導入したい、ということかなとも思いました。
とすると、"github alternatives on-premises" などのキーワードで検索すると候補がヒットすると思います。例えば:

- [6 Github alternatives that are open source and self-hosted - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/github-alternatives-open-source-seflt-hosted)
- [5 open source alternatives to GitHub | Opensource.com](https://opensource.com/article/20/11/open-source-alternatives-github)

([上記リンク先にも有ります](https://opensource.com/life/16/8/how-construct-your-own-git-server-part-6)が)githooksを活用して素のGitで管理する、というのも確かにこれらの選択肢のうちのひとつとして存在します。

大半はUnix系OSが前提となっており、Windowsでの選択肢は限られると思います。

私が知っている範囲では、[GitBucket](https://gitbucket.github.io/)はJVM上で動作するので、Windows上にも導入できます([参考](https://sukkiri.jp/technologies/devtools/gitbucket/gitbucket_install.html))。

Comment: タイトルに ”githubを利用しない” とあるように、現在のところはgithubのようなホスティングサービスを使用したくありません。　にも関わらず、検索キーやそのたの情報に "GitHub" が頻繁に出没するのは何故ですか？
私は更に混乱しています。

Comment: こちらの回答は、「本当の意図は、外部ホスティングサービスを利用せずに」ということではないか、という考察を踏まえた回答になります。ここに記載したものは、GitHubサービスと異なり、オンプレで(セルフホスティングで)利用するものです。GitHubがキーワードになっているのは、"GitHubに似たもの"を探すためです。 / githooks 方式にこだわる理由は何か有るのですか？(有るのであれば本文に追記お願いします)

Comment: 「本当の意図は、外部ホスティングサービスを利用せずに」は合致しています。　そして、Githooksに拘っているわけではありません。
「どういう環境で何を実現したいか」の観点について回答させて戴いたように、ホスティングサービス（GitHubなど）を使用せず、Git（SourceTree，Git for Windows）環境で、
"開発者が作業しているクローンからPushしてベアリポジトリを更新した際、他の開発者に更新したことをメールで通知させPullを促す" ためにはどうすれば良いかだけです。
私がローカルネットワーク上でできる方法は、Githooks機能を利用するのみ、は正しいですか？
GitHubのようなホスティングサービスでは、Githooks機能を利用するか、リクエストプル機能を利用する、は正しいですか？
そして、2011年頃(v1.7.7)に "post-commit"と"post-receive"を削除し機能が含まれないとありますが、つまり機能を利用できないということになりますが、
2019/3/21発行の「Gitポケットリファレンス」にpost-commit、post-recieveが記載されています。　この意味を教えてください。
本文にやりとりの一部を追加しました。　よろしくお願いします。